# Can not open service error

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written a windows service. I am trying to start the service from my web applicaiton.

```
ServiceController svcContrl = new ServiceController("TestService");
svcContrl.Start();
```

I can see the service in My Computer->Manage->Service. If I start the service from there manually, it works fine. But when I try to run the code, I am getting an exception " Cannot open TestService service on [ComputerName]".

I have given access to aspnet user, windows login user to service, bin/debug folders still getting this exception when the code runs.
Am i missing something which is causing this exception?

Comment: What is the question?  This isn't a debugging forum; it's a programming forum, so you should ask something specific.

Comment: are you trying to start the windows service from an ASP.NET/IIS application ?

Comment: Look in the event log to see what's going on.

Comment: Event Log also shows the same thing. Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Cannot open TestService service on computer [ComputerName].

Comment: InvalidOperationException means the service was not found.  I think you're using the wrong name.

Comment: Chris, i can see that service in Services list. I copy Paste'd the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I am using Windows 2008 R2 IIS 6.1. It by default connects as Network service. Hence I needed to change the basic settings of my virtual directory and set it to connect as my machine log in credentials. Thanks All and especially Chris.

Answer (score 1):

The InvalidOperationException can be thrown when the service isn't located or if there is a bug within the service itself preventing it from starting.

Given that you said you can start the service directly through the MMC app, it sounds like maybe you have the wrong name for the service in your code.

Try the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd.aspx to see if the service can be started/stopped/etc.

This code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyd7kz8c(v=vs.90).aspx) shows how to get a list of services on the system.  Might be useful to determine the actual service name.

And, here is a sample app that starts/stops services: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31688/Using-the-ServiceController-in-C-to-stop-and-start

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried to get the services list running. I got this exception. "Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '[Computer Name'. This operation might require other privileges." I have admin privilege on this machine

Comment: @rohit: What is the context here? Do you have a asp.net site that's trying to start a service?  If so, it doesn't matter what your priviledges are.  What matters is the priviledges of the user that the site is executing under.  What is that account?

Comment: Chris, u got it right. hv it hosted in my local IIS. I created a stand alone application just to test the Service, and it works perfectly. But when I host it in IIS,it fails. How can I give access to IIS user ?